# Sequelize nested include without null properties

Tags: postgresql, express, nested, sequelize.js, include

using ExpressJs/Postgres/Sequelize and when doing findOne I am getting an object return that contains nested objects with following data in the response:

```
        "CompanyVolume": null,
        "CompanyMarkets": [],
```

Is there a way to avoid receiving these properties with null/[] from Postgres?

Appreciate any thoughts...:)

```
const kyc = await db.Kyc.findOne({
      where: {id: req.params.id},
      include: [       
        {model: db.Company,
          include: [
            { model: db.CompanyStakeholder, through: db.Role },
            { model: db.CompanyDelivery,
              // where: {
              //   deliveryAverageDurationAmount: {[Op.not]:null},
              // }
              //returns Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'not')
            },
            { model: db.CompanyVolume },
            { model: db.CompanyDelivery },
            { model: db.CompanyMarket },
      ],
      nest: true,
    })
```

the response object with properties including null or empty arrays

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "kycTitle": "KYC1006428",
        "kycPasscode": null,
        "kycDescription": "The best kyc ever, lorem epsum sanctus vita loca",
        "kycStartDate": "2022-01-28",
        "kycStatus": null,
        "kycConsent": "approved",
        "kycConsentDate": "2022-01-27T14:01:39.924Z",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-27T13:19:41.649Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-01-27T14:01:39.919Z",
        "id_User": 1,
        "Company": {
            "id": 6,
            "companyName": "Niky",
            "companyEntityType": null,
            "companyVatNumber": "",
            "companyRegistrationNumber": "",
            "companyPubliclyListed": null,
            "companyAddress1": "Pepovej 234",
            "companyAddress2": "",
            "companyCity": "Dada",
            "companyPostCode": "3400",
            "companyCountry": "Owner",
            "companyPhone": "+21321321231",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-27T13:19:41.669Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-01-27T13:19:41.676Z",
            "KycId": 5,
            "CompanyStakeholders": [], //I don't want this returned
            "CompanyDelivery": null,   //I don't want this returned
            "CompanyVolume": null,     //I don't want this returned
            "CompanyMarkets": [],      //I don't want this returned
        },     
    }
]
```

The different Associations:

```
  Company.associate = function (models) {
    Company.hasOne(models.Contact)
    Company.hasOne(models.CompanyDelivery)
    Company.hasMany(models.CompanyMarket)
    Company.hasMany(models.CompanyPosBilling)
    Company.hasMany(models.CompanySettlement)
    Company.hasOne(models.CompanySubscription)
    Company.hasOne(models.CompanyVolume)
    Company.hasMany(models.CompanyWebsite)
    Company.belongsTo(models.Kyc)
    Company.belongsToMany(models.CompanyStakeholder, {
      through: models.Role,
      unique: false
    })
  }

 CompanyDelivery.associate = function (models) {
    CompanyDelivery.belongsTo(models.Company)
  }

  CompanyMarket.associate = function (models) {
    CompanyMarket.belongsTo(models.Company)
  }

  Kyc.associate = function (models) {
    Kyc.hasOne(models.Company)
  }

  CompanyStakeholder.associate = function (models) {
    CompanyStakeholder.belongsToMany(models.Company, {
      through: models.Role,
      unique: false
    })
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `avoid`? Do you want to get only record where these lined records is not null or has records?

Comment: @Anatoly I only want to get records where those properties are not null. In other words, I only want to get those if they have data inside.
>`CompanyStakeholders": [], //I don't want this returned`
>`CompanyDelivery": null,   //I don't want this returned`
....